# How to determine which persons are close to you from a database

Tags: android, geolocation, distance

Let's say we have a few 100.000 people and they all share their location. 
Their location is stored in a database online as Geopoint.

If I open an app on my device and I only want to show the let's say 50 closest people, what would be the way to approach this.

I know I can just retrieve every bodies location from that database and check the distance for every single device. But that seems to be not a very effective way. Especially if it would become millions of people.

What is the proper way to approach this?

Comment: It really depends on your database setup. There are database extensions for spatial data and queries which might provide you with decent performance out of the box. It also depends on your needs for accuracy. As a first step you could query a sub-set of locations that are within a square around the query location. Since that does not involve trigonometric functions but only finding numbers in 2-D ranges that should be quick enough as a first approximation. If you need more accuracy you can run a more precise query on that result-set.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that.